# ListView View object has no attribute 'object'

Tags: python, html, django

I used to have the view as a DetailView but when I wanted to add pagination I needed to change the view to a ListView. But since doing this it has started throwing this error: `'CategoryDetailView' object has no attribute 'object'` I believe I need to assign category's to self but I am not 100% sure how to do this.

I have tried:

```
def category(self , request , *args , **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return self.object
```

But it didn't work so this is what it is at the moment.

View:

```
class CategoryDetailView(ListView):
    model = Category
    paginate_by = 1

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CategoryDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['category_posts'] = Post.objects.filter(live=True, category=self.object)
        return context
```

Thanks guys

Comment: What are you paginating over, the categories or the posts?

Comment: Well this does not look like a `ListView`, but a `DetailView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using a `DetailView`

A `ListView` is used to render, well, a list of objects of the `model` you specify. Here however, you only want to retrieve a *single* `Category`, and the `Post`s of that category, you thus should use a [**`DetailView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.detail.DetailView). As specified in the documentation, such view contains a `self.object`:

> While this view is executing, **`self.object` will contain the object** that the view is operating upon.

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView

class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Category

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CategoryDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['category_posts'] = self.object.post_set.filter(live=True)
        return context
```

it furthermore does not make much sense to use a `paginate_by` attribute, since a `DetailView` of course always renders exactly *one* element.

In the URL, you probably specify a parameter named `pk`, or a parameter named `slug` (given a `Category` has a `slug` field). The `DetailView` will automatically retrieve the `Category` that corresponds with this `pk`/`slug`.

## Using a `ListView`

Alternatively, you can use a `ListView`, but in that case a `ListView` of `Post`s. Indeed, we can construct such `ListView` like:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

class CategoryDetailView(ListView):
    model = Post
    paginate_by = 20

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(category__id=self.kwargs['pk'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['category'] = Category.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return context
```

So here we can fetch the relavant `Category` by accessing the `pk` in the URL parameters. We here implement the listview however *over the `Post`s*.

Comment: I need a paginate by as there are going to be a lot of posts, and I cannot have this all on one page

Comment: @MaxLoyd: in that case this is a `ListView` over `Post`s, and then you should filter on the category id, will update.

Comment: Ahh okay I thought that would be the case, thank you

Comment: @MaxLoyd: see edit. Of course it might require some extra "polishing".

Comment: The category uses a slug, would you mind showing me how to filter through a category's slug

Comment: @MaxLoyd: just the filtering (in both `get_queryset` and `get_context_data` with `slug=self.kwargs['slug']` instead of `id=...`.